# C++ QuickSort Algorithm keeps crashing

Tags: c++, sorting, loops, recursion, quicksort

Trying to implement a Quick Sort algorithm.I think the problem is with the recursion, but I do not know what I should do to fix it. The program continues to crash every time I run it, and I cannot understand why. Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int pIndex;

int Partition(int *A,int start,int end){

int pivot;
int pIndex;
 if(start<end){
    int pivot=A[end];
    int pIndex=start;
    for(int x=0;x<end;x++){
        if(A[x]<A[end]){
            swap(A[x],A[pIndex]);
             pIndex=pIndex+1;   
        }   
    }
    swap(A[pIndex],A[end]);
 }
//cout<<pIndex<<endl;
swap(A[pIndex],A[end]);
return pIndex;
};
void QuickSort(int *A, int start,int end){
    if(start<end)
    {

    pIndex=Partition(A,start,end);
    QuickSort(A,pIndex+1,end);
    QuickSort(A,start,pIndex-1);
}
};
int main(){

int A[10]{4,23,1,43,2,10};  
//Partition(A,0,9);
QuickSort(A,0,5);
for(int x=0;x<10;x++){
    cout<< A[x]<<" ";
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the program under a debugger? What line does it show the crash on?

Comment: You should not put a semicolon after the `}` at the end of a function; it is a null statement or null declaration.  That is, however, completely unrelated to your crash.

Comment: The answer given solves your crash, however, I think you have to revisit the logic of your algorithm since partition will never work as you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your partition algorithm is about twice as much code as it needs to be. You seem to be always choosing the *last* element in the sequence for your pivot, and although not advisable, it will work for academic demonstration.

**Your Crash**

You're defining two `pIndex` values, only one of which is actually deterministic. You also declare two `pivot` variables, but that does NOT cause your crash (the first one is never used). It should be cleaned up none-the-less, but the death knell in your code is duplicate `pIndex`

```
int pivot;
int pIndex;     // HERE
if(start<end){
    int pivot=A[end];
    int pIndex=start; // HERE AGAIN
    for(int x=0;x<end;x++){
        if(A[x]<A[end]){
            swap(A[x],A[pIndex]);
            pIndex=pIndex+1;   
        }   
    }
    swap(A[pIndex],A[end]);
}
swap(A[pIndex],A[end]); // uses non-determined pIndex
return pIndex; // returns non-determined pIndex
```

Changing `int pIndex=start;` to simply be `pIndex=start;` will solve your crash, but your partition method still needs... help.

---

**The "Sweep" Partition Method**

The "sweep" method of partitioning is generally done like this for a pivot value that is assumed to be right-tailed, and you would be hard pressed to get this simpler (invoking [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) not withstanding):

```
size_t Partition(int *A, size_t len)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return 0;

    size_t pvt = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i<end; ++i)
    {
        if (A[i] < a[len-1])
            std::swap(A[i], A[pvt++])
    }
    std::swap(A[pvt], a[len-1]);
    return pvt;
};
```

The above algorithm includes only the necessities needed for a partition: the sequence iterator (a pointer in your case), and the sequence length. Everything else is deterministic based on those two items. A quick sample program of how this works follows, with a purposely placed 5 for the pivot value:

```
#include <iostream>

size_t Partition(int *A, size_t len)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return 0;

    size_t pvt = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i<len-1; ++i)
    {
        if (A[i] < A[len-1])
            std::swap(A[i], A[pvt++]);
    }
    std::swap(A[pvt], A[len-1]);
    return pvt;
};

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 4, 8, 7, 3, 9, 2, 1, 6, 5 };
    size_t n = Partition(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));
    std::cout << "Partition : " << n << '\n';
    for (auto x : arr)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Output**

```
Partition : 4
4 3 2 1 5 7 8 6 9
```

---

**How To Invoke From  QuickSort**

Invoking a partition in quicksort sets up the pivot location, which becomes the "end" iteration point of the bottom segment, and the one-BEFORE iteration point of the top segment. It is **critical** the pivot location returned from an invoke of `Partition()` should NOT be included in *either* subsequence when recursing.

```
void QuickSort(int *A, size_t len)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    size_t pvt = Partition(A, len);
    QuickSort(A, pvt++);        // NOTE: post increment...
    QuickSort(A+pvt, len-pvt);  // ...which makes this skip the pivot
}
```

Yeah, pointer arithmetic rocks, don't you think?

---

**Putting It All Together**

The program below incorporates *both* the `Partition` and `QuickSort` :

```
#include <iostream>

size_t Partition(int *A, size_t len)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return 0;

    size_t pvt = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i<len-1; ++i)
    {
        if (A[i] < A[len-1])
            std::swap(A[i], A[pvt++]);
    }
    std::swap(A[pvt], A[len-1]);
    return pvt;
};

void QuickSort(int *A, size_t len)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    size_t pvt = Partition(A, len);
    QuickSort(A, pvt++);            // NOTE: post increment
    QuickSort(A+pvt, len-pvt);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 4, 8, 7, 3, 9, 2, 1, 6, 5 };
    QuickSort(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));
    for (auto x : arr)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed the issue. I appreciate all the work put into your post :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In this part:

```
int pivot;
int pIndex;
 if(start<end){
    int pivot=A[end];
    int pIndex=start;
```

You are defining two pivots, and two pIndex's. You are not using the pivot at all, and with the last swap you are using the uninitialized pIndex. This should work:

```
int Partition(int *A,int start,int end){    
    int pIndex = start;
    if(start<end){
        for(int x=0;x<end;x++){
            if(A[x]<A[end]){
                swap(A[x],A[pIndex]);
                pIndex=pIndex+1;   
            }
        }
        swap(A[pIndex],A[end]);
    }   
    swap(A[pIndex],A[end]);
    return pIndex;
}
```

Comment: That does not work. The output is `23 10 2 43 4 1 0 0 0 0` (although it does not crash at least)

Comment: When I substitute this function in, it does fix the crash. but absolutely nothing appears on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also something of a C++ newbie, but I find myself curious about what happens when start >= end. It looks as though your Partition function will still return a pIndex value, but I don't see where you define it anywhere. If (as I suspect) it returns whatever value happens to reside in memory, then you'll very likely end up referencing some undefined memory locations when you use A[pIndex]

Comment: your observation of `pIndex` never being set is spot-on.